# How to Jest.mock redux-form's Field

Tags: testing, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

My react class components looks like this:

```
import { Field, reduxForm, propTypes } from 'redux-form';

class DepositAmountInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Field
          component={NumberInputField}
          props={{
            onChange: this.handleInput,
            onBlur: this.handleOnBlur
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default DepositAmountInput
```

In my Jest test for this component, how can I mock the Field component of redux-form? I am looking for something like this:

> .mock('redux-form/lib/Field', () => 'Field');

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is the code which runs perfectly well on my test ( see picture below )

`jest.mock('redux-form/lib/Field', () => 'field');`

(same as the one you were expecting then. )

on my pacakage.json :

`{
    "redux-form": "^7.0.3",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
}`

[image: screenshot]